# How to draw a solid of revolution of a polynomial function around the y-axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, 3d

A solid of revolution of a function `y = x**2` around the y-axis can be plotted using the code below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d as axes3d
from matplotlib import cm

np.seterr(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore')

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')


ll, ul = 0, 1 
u = np.linspace(ll, ul, 60)
v = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 60)
U, V = np.meshgrid(u, v)

Z = U

X = np.sqrt(Z)*np.cos(V)
Y = np.sqrt(Z)*np.sin(V)

ax.set_xlabel('Y axis')
ax.set_ylabel('X axis')
ax.set_zlabel('Z axis')

ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap=plt.cm.YlGnBu_r)

plt.show()
```

This code just plots the solid of revolution of the function `x = sqrt(y)` which is the inverse of `y = x**2`. But how to draw the solid of revolution for a function as:

```
y = x**5 + x**4 + x**3 + x**2 + x
```

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mapping from `(U,V)` parameter space to `(X,Y,Z)` coordinates can be very flexible.
Often `U` is chosen to be something like `np.linspace(ll, ul, 100)` and is taken to be equal to `Y` (if `y` is the axis of rotation). But you don't have to use `U` that way. 
Instead `U` could represent the radius:

```
ll, ul = 0, 1 
u = np.linspace(ll, ul, 100)
v = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 60)
U, V = np.meshgrid(u, v)
```

and then `X`, `Y`, `Z` can be defined in terms of the radius, `U`:

```
Y = U**5 + U**4 + U**3 + U**2 + U
X = U*np.cos(V)
Z = U*np.sin(V)
```

---

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d as axes3d
from matplotlib import cm

np.seterr(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore')

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

ll, ul = 0, 1 
u = np.linspace(ll, ul, 100)
v = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 60)
U, V = np.meshgrid(u, v)

Y = U**5 + U**4 + U**3 + U**2 + U
X = U*np.cos(V)
Z = U*np.sin(V)

ax.set_xlabel('Y axis')
ax.set_ylabel('X axis')
ax.set_zlabel('Z axis')

ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap=plt.cm.YlGnBu_r)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Yes. I did the same but I was not sure why it worked and that's why I asked you.