# Python3 Matplotlib to Show Solid of Revolution from Method of Disks, Method of Shells, and Method of Washers around x-axis and y-axis

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I have created this topic before: [How to Add another subplot to show Solid of Revolution toward x-axis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74970235/how-to-add-another-subplot-to-show-solid-of-revolution-toward-x-axis/74972856#74972856)

I want to plot the solid from a curve 3 + 2x - x^2 that is revolved about:

a. the x-axis

b. the y-axis

c. the line y = -1

d. the line x = 4

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

this is my MWE (the problem is to find the inverse of 3 + 2x - x^2 is not something easy thus I have no idea how to make this code works):

```
# Compare the plot at xy axis with the solid of revolution toward x and y axis
# For function x=(y)^(3/2)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

n = 100

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(14, 7))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(221)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(222, projection='3d')
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(223)
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(224, projection='3d')
y = np.linspace(0, 9, n)
x = (y) ** (3 / 2)
t = np.linspace(0, np.pi * 2, n)

xn = np.outer(x, np.cos(t))
yn = np.outer(x, np.sin(t))
zn = np.zeros_like(xn)
for i in range(len(x)):
    zn[i:i + 1, :] = np.full_like(zn[0, :], y[i])

ax1.plot(x, y)
ax1.set_title("$f(x)$")
ax2.plot_surface(xn, yn, zn)
ax2.set_title("$f(x)$: Revolution around $y$")

# find the inverse of the function
x_inverse = y
y_inverse = np.power(x_inverse, 3 / 2)
xn_inverse = np.outer(x_inverse, np.cos(t))
yn_inverse = np.outer(x_inverse, np.sin(t))
zn_inverse = np.zeros_like(xn_inverse)
for i in range(len(x_inverse)):
    zn_inverse[i:i + 1, :] = np.full_like(zn_inverse[0, :], y_inverse[i])

ax3.plot(x_inverse, y_inverse)
ax3.set_title("Inverse of $f(x)$")
ax4.plot_surface(xn_inverse, yn_inverse, zn_inverse)
ax4.set_title("$f(x)$: Revolution around $x$")

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: You already have a `y_inverse`. What specifically is wrong with it?

Comment: What should I put on that `y_inverse` then? the inverse of `3 + 2x - x^2` is not easy to be calculated thus I can't just put this `x_inverse = y
y_inverse = np.power(x_inverse, 3 / 2)`

Comment: Swap your x and y variables. Now you have an inverse, right?